# fix position inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an arrow image that gets you back to the top of the page when you click on it... I would like this arrow to have a fixed position inside its div parent.

Here's the code:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.up {
  float: right;
  max-width: 3%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<section class="elements relative" id="about">
  <a href="">
    <img src="img/arrow-up.png" class="up" id="up-about" alt="" />
  </a>
  <h2>Qui suis-je &#63;</h2>
  <p>Lots of text</p>
</section>
```

This makes my white arrow stay on the screen wherever I go on the page. However I would like it to only stay within my "relative" section but not go out of it (if I go below or over this section in my scrolling).
Is there a simple way to do this? I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: Do you mean that the position of that arrow is absolute?

Comment: Try `position: absolute` on `.up`

Comment: @QuyTruong - no it is fixed. This way it stays within my div. What I want it to do though is to "move" within the div as I scroll. If I put the position on absolute, it stays in the top right corner of my "elements relative" div...
My position fixed actually make it disappear so for now I have no "position"... position absolute makes it show

Answer (score 2):

You should use `position:absolute;` instead of `position:fixed;` for your **arrow**, therefore it won't be fixed in the same place when you scroll your page. Here you go:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.up {
  max-width: 3%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<section class="elements relative" id="about">
  <a href="">
    <img src="img/arrow-up.png" class="up" id="up-about" alt="" />
  </a>
  <h2>Qui suis-je &#63;</h2>
  <p>Lots of text</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it doesn't achieve what I would like. I want the arrow (.up) to move within the div as I am scrolling - the div is quite big and if I have it in absolute position (or fixed with float right), it only stays in the upper right corner of my div.
Sorry, my question did not make that clear...

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/denea/o2z1o26c/42/
I hope I understood your request right.

Comment: Ah! Almost - Now the div itself scrolls "under" the arrow. If you want, you can go to the website itself: http://berglind-margo.com/ When you click on either "travail" or "qui suis-je" you'll see the whole thing. The thing is I would like the arrow to scroll over the div but not the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute` on `.up` (and no float)

```
.up {
  max-width: 3%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it doesn't achieve what I would like. I want the arrow (.up) to move within the div as I am scrolling - the div is quite big and if I have it in absolute position (or fixed with float right), it only stays in the upper right corner of my div.
Sorry, my question did not make that clear...